# How to get DT::datatable to update when hidden

Tags: r, datatable, shiny

When `datatable`s are hidden in Shiny, they seem to not update, even if `outputOptions(output, 'tableID', suspendWhenHidden=FALSE)` is used. Below is an MRE. If you hide the `datatable`, and then add or delete rows, and then show the `datatable`, you'll see that it's not updated. However, as soon as you modify the `datatable` while it's visible, all past changes "catch up" with it. How can we force `datatable`s to redraw themselves while they're hidden?

```
#ui
shinyUI(
  #tags$head(tags$script(src="main.js")),
  fluidPage(    
    titlePanel("Modifying Hidden Datatable"),
    sidebarLayout(      
      sidebarPanel(
        actionButton("decrease", "Decrease Row Number"),
        actionButton("increase", "Increase Row Number"),
        actionButton("hide", "Hide Data Table"),
        actionButton("show", "Show Data Table")
      ),
      mainPanel(
        tags$head(tags$script(src="main.js")),
        DT::dataTableOutput("df")  
      )
    )
  )
)

#server
library(shiny)
library(DT)

shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

  values = reactiveValues(n = 1)

  observeEvent(input$decrease, {
    values$n = values$n - 1
    if (values$n == 0) values$n = 1
  })

  observeEvent(input$increase, {
    values$n = values$n + 1
    if (values$n > nrow(mtcars)) values$n = nrow(mtcars)
  })

  output$df = renderDataTable({
    df = mtcars[1:values$n, ]
    DT::datatable(df)
  })
  outputOptions(output, "df", suspendWhenHidden=FALSE)
})

#javascript
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#hide').click(function() {
    $('#df').hide();
  });
  $('#show').click(function() {
    $('#df').show();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that if you're already using Javascript, you can just call the `draw` function on the table. The following Javascript code should work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#hide').click(function() {
    $('#df').hide();
  });
  $('#show').click(function() {
    $('#df').show();
    $("#df table").DataTable().draw();
  });
});
```