# Shiny: update DT on inactive tabPanel

Tags: javascript, jquery, r, shiny, dt

TL;DR: How to force drawing datatable when it is on inactive tab but its input changes?

A have a shiny app which looks like that:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
shinyApp(

  ui = fluidPage(

    sidebarLayout(

      sidebarPanel(
        numericInput(
          inputId = "random_val",
          label = "pick random value",
          value = 1
        )
      ),

      mainPanel(
        tabsetPanel(
          id = "tabset",
          tabPanel(
            title = "some_other_tab",
            "Some other stuff"
          ),
          tabPanel(
            title = "test_render",
            textOutput("echo_test"),
            DTOutput("dt_test")
          )
        )
      )
    )
  ),

  server = function(input, output) {

    output$echo_test <- renderText({
      cat("renderText called \n")
      input$random_val
    })
    outputOptions(output, "echo_test", suspendWhenHidden = FALSE)

    output$dt_test <- renderDT({
      cat("renderDT called \n")
      df <- data.frame(
        a = 1:10^6,
        b = rep(input$random_val, 10^6)
      )
      datatable(df)
    })
    outputOptions(output, "dt_test", suspendWhenHidden = FALSE)
  }

)
```

My problem is the following: When the input ( `input$random_value` ) changes while the tab `test_render` (i.e., the one with `DT`) is open, everything works properly. However, when the tab containing `DT` is not active while the user changes its input, `DT` does not get updated, even though `suspendWhenHidden = FALSE` is set and `renderDT` seems to be called.

I have found an [open issue](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/1364) complaining about similar problem but no solution was offered.

I have also found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38514472/how-to-get-dtdatatable-to-update-when-hidden) and tried to adapt it to my problem. So far I am successful with updating `DT` by running `$("#dt_test table").DataTable().draw();` from browser console. `DT` also gets updated when it is clicked (e.g., on the sort button).

I am looking for a way to update `DT` *immediately* on input changes (or its initialization), no matter if it is on active panel or not. A special case of this problem that is especially troublesome is when the app is started -- `DT` is not rendered immediately. It seems the drawing starts only when the tab on which it's located is opened (it shows *Processing...*). In my actual app this introduces couple of seconds lag -- that's why I want to force processing `DT` while the user is looking at *some other tab*.

I experimented with including a javascript file that runs `$("#dt_test table").DataTable().draw();` on various [events](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/js-events.html) but so far without success.

Is there a way to achieve what I am looking for with the aforementioned events or any other method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have come up with two possible solutions.

1. By using an observer, but with this solution the table will update when switching to the datatable tab, not before.

This was inspired by two videos that are really helpful to better understand how shiny works:

[Shiny developer conference 2016](https://www.rstudio.com/resources/webinars/shiny-developer-conference/) - firs two listed videos

2. By using the proxy object, this option requires server side processing by setting the appropriate option when rendering the table (see code for this solution below)

Solution 1

```
    library(shiny)
    library(DT)
    shinyApp(

            ui = fluidPage(

                    sidebarLayout(

                            sidebarPanel(
                                    numericInput(
                                            inputId = "random_val",
                                            label = "pick random value",
                                            value = 1
                                    )
                            ),

                            mainPanel(
                                    tabsetPanel(
                                            id = "tabset",
                                            tabPanel(
                                                    title = "some_other_tab",
                                                    "Some other stuff"
                                            ),
                                            tabPanel(
                                                    title = "test_render",
                                                    textOutput("echo_test"),
                                                    DTOutput("dt_test")
                                            )
                                    )
                            )
                    )
            ),

            server = function(input, output) {

                    output$echo_test <- renderText({
                            cat("renderText called \n")
                            input$random_val
                    })
                    outputOptions(output, "echo_test", suspendWhenHidden = FALSE)

                    observeEvent(input$random_val, {
                            cat("renderDT called \n")
                            df <- data.frame(
                                    a = 1:10^6,
                                    b = rep(input$random_val, 10^6)
                            )   
                            output$dt_test <- renderDT(df)
                    })
            }
    )
```

Solution 2

```
    library(shiny)
    library(DT)
    shinyApp(

            ui = fluidPage(

                    sidebarLayout(

                            sidebarPanel(
                                    numericInput(
                                            inputId = "random_val",
                                            label = "pick random value",
                                            value = 1
                                    )
                            ),

                            mainPanel(
                                    tabsetPanel(
                                            id = "tabset",
                                            selected = "test_render",
                                            tabPanel(
                                                    title = "some_other_tab",
                                                    "Some other stuff"
                                            ),
                                            tabPanel(
                                                    title = "test_render",
                                                    textOutput("echo_test"),
                                                    DTOutput("dt_test")
                                            )
                                    )
                            )
                    )
            ),

            server = function(input, output, session) {

                    output$echo_test <- renderText({
                            cat("renderText called \n")
                            input$random_val
                    })
                    outputOptions(output, "echo_test", suspendWhenHidden = FALSE)
                    output$dt_test <- renderDT({
                            cat("renderDT called \n")
                            df <- data.frame(
                                    a = 1:10^6,
                                    b = rep(1, 10^6)
                            )
                            datatable(df)
                    }, server = TRUE)
                    observeEvent(input$random_val, {
                            df <- data.frame(
                                    a = 1:10^6,
                                    b = rep(input$random_val, 10^6)
                            )
                            dt_test_proxy <- dataTableProxy("dt_test", session = shiny::getDefaultReactiveDomain(),
                                                            deferUntilFlush = TRUE)
                            replaceData(dt_test_proxy, df)
                            cat("table updated \n")
                    })
                    updateTabsetPanel(session, "tabset", selected = "some_other_tab")
            }
    )
```

Let me know if this helps....

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer. That's a step in the right direction -- it solves half of the problem I described. Remaining issue is that your solution works only after the `test_render` tab has been visited. The first time you open it, datatable is not yet rendered/drawn with initilized input (i.e., 1). Is it possible to achieve also that?

Comment: Have you tried solution 2 with server side rendering which does not wait for the tab to be active?

Comment: Yes, I tested this and the result is as described. In addition, with Solution 2 when I start the app, change the input and then open the `test_render` tab, datatable is rendered with default 1's in b column instead of new input

Comment: With a workaround I was able to fix that the first render is displayed with the correct value of input$random_val. Regarding how to avoid the first render starting only when the tab is activaded I don't have a solution so far. What is clear if you check with crome develper tools this part of HTML is generated on the fly when you activate the tab. I guess the solution is then to find a way how to force Shiny to generate earlier, but so far I didn't find a way. Will keep trying in the coming days. Interesing problem...

Comment: Hello, you were close -- I found a solution with a slight modification of your **Solution 2**. 
1) Take `session` as arg to server ( `server = function(input, output, session)` ),
2) add arg `selected = "test_render"` in ui's `tabsetPanel`
3) add the following at the end of `server`: `updateTabsetPanel(session, "tabset", selected = "some_other_tab")`. 
With this workaround, datatable will get rendered at the app start (it's tab is active for a very short time) and the rest will work fine as in your code. **Please add this modification to your Solution 2 and I will accept your answer**.

Comment: Hi! I have modified Solution 2 as per your comment. Glad we found a solution!

Answer (score 0):

According to this [thread](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/shiny-discuss/4E61F-tvGR4/tJKGGELLAQAJ), DT widgets don't render if they're hidden on the page: 
https://github.com/rstudio/DT/blob/ca5e7645b42c021137d4333c2f781b62abf32ad1/inst/htmlwidgets/datatables.js#L113

more specifically, if the `offsetWidth` and `offsetHeight` of their DOM element are 0, which happens if they or one of their parents have been hidden with `display: none`. That's how `tabPanel` and `conditionalPanel` hide their contents.

One workaround might be to bypass `tabPanel` and conditionally render the DT yourself using the [`visibility`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/visibility) property. When an element has `visibility: hidden`, it's not shown, but it does take up space.

Here's an example of this:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

hiddenPanel <- function(...) {
  div(style = "visibility: hidden;", ...)
}

toggleVisibility <- function(id, visible, session = getDefaultReactiveDomain()) {
  session$sendCustomMessage("toggle-visibility", list(id = id, visible = visible))
}

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    tags$head(
      tags$script("
        Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler('toggle-visibility', function(msg) {
          $('#' + msg.id).css('visibility', msg.visible ? 'visible' : 'hidden');
        });
      ")
    ),

    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        numericInput(
          inputId = "random_val",
          label = "pick random value",
          value = 1
        )
      ),

      mainPanel(
        tabsetPanel(
          id = "tabset",
          tabPanel(
            title = "some_other_tab",
            "Some other stuff"
          ),
          tabPanel(
            title = "test_render"
          )
        ),

        hiddenPanel(
          id = "dt_test_panel",
          DTOutput("dt_test")
        )
      )
    )
  ),

  server = function(input, output, session) {
    output$dt_test <- renderDT({
      cat("renderDT called \n")
      df <- data.frame(
        a = 1:10^4,
        b = rep(input$random_val, 10^4)
      )
      datatable(df)
    })

    observeEvent(input$tabset, {
      toggleVisibility("dt_test_panel", input$tabset == "test_render")
    })
  }
)
```

Note that you don't need to set `suspendWhenHidden = FALSE` here. And I would be wary of using that too, since I think the bug still exists where a DT might not update when `suspendWhenHidden = FALSE`, and the DT is in a tabPanel or conditionalPanel.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer. While this solution achieves exactly what I asked for, it generates another problem:
1) start the app and go to test_render tab, 2) change the input, 3) while the datatable shows "*Processing...*" quickly click on some_other_tab. If you do this, you end up with datatable shown on a tab it is not supposed to be for ~1-2 seconds and then disappear. So yes, it is a valid answer, but from the ux perspective, this side-effect is more problematic than the original problem.